# Usar AdminLTE con DataTable Responsivo

Tags: datatables, adminlte

Estoy usando la plantilla AdminLTE y entre sus dependencias esta DataTables, realmente funciona pero no es responsivo ni tampoco me habilita el boton + para ver mas detalles.

En la documentación el ejemplo se ve así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a mi me aparece asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy añadiendo de la siguiente forma.

```
@import "admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min";
@import "admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min";
@import "admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min";

window.$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
var dt = require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min")();
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min")();
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min")
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min"

<table id="categories-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-priority="0">ID</th>
    <th data-priority="1">Nombre</th>
    <th data-priority="3">Descripción</th>
    <th data-priority="2">Acciones</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

$("#categories-datatable").dataTable({
            "retrieve": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": $("#categories-datatable").data("source")
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "description"},
                {"data": "actions"}
            ],
            responsive: true
        });
```

Todas las funciones de datatables trabajan bien, lo unico es que al redimensionar la pagina no cambia el tamaño

Answer (score 0):

En la definición de la tabla, en lugar de *width="100%"* utiliza *style="width: 100%"*:

```
<table id="..." class="..." style="width: 100%">
```